# 403 Forbidden when using @Secured Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to secure a rest API created in Spring Boot using Spring Security, specifically the @Secured annotation. I am trying to follow this article: https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration (Spring Security 2.1.6.RELEASE).

I have a method in my `@RestController` class, called `getUsers()`, which looks like this:

```
    @Secured("USER_READ")
    @RequestMapping(value = USER_STRING, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @JsonView(UserViews.ExternalLight.class)
    public Iterable<User> getUsers(@RequestBody(required = false) SearchContext context) {
        return getUsersHelper(context);
    }
```

Ideally I would like there to be a privilege called "USER_READ" that any role that should be able to read users would have (I intend for more than just ADMIN and USER roles).

In my `UserPrinciple implements UserDetails` class, I have the following method:

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return getAuthorities(user.getRoles());
}
```

When I attempt to access the API with good credentials, and debug this line, I see that `getAuthorities()` returns a list of `SimpleGrantedAuthority` objects, containing "USER_READ", as well as "ROLE_ADMIN" and some others. However, as the title suggests, I am still getting a 403 despite "USER_READ" still being present in the list of `GrantedAuthority` objects.

I have seen articles saying I need to prefix roles with "ROLE_", but I have done that for my roles, and if I change `@Secured("USER_READ")` to `@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")`, I still receive the same error.

I have also enabled method security using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)`.

I am quite new to Spring, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide the code of your security configuration